# Execute click event on load

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a click event function like so:

```
        $('.expand2').click(function(e) {
            alert('in');
            e.preventDefault();
            var obj = $(this);
...
```

I need to execute it after page load, as well as clicking on the link with class="expand2".

How would i simulate a click event right after the page load for the first  on the form with a class "expand2"??

I've tried this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.expand2:first').click();
}
```

didn't work.

Comment: You are missing a `);` at the end of your second snippet. Also, the click handler must be bound before you trigger the click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(document).ready(function() { ... })` is just shorthand for `$(function() { ... })` so that shouldn't be your problem. Provided you've copied the code correctly, it just looks as though you forgot to close your brackets

EDIT: roXon's demo with $(function(){}) just to show you it works the same
http://jsfiddle.net/rWbUD/1/

Answer (score 2):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/rWbUD/)

```
$('.expand2').click(function(){
   alert('clicked')
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.expand2:first').click();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.expand2:first').click();
})
```

See the [documents](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for this.

If this doesn't work can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.expand2:first').click();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.expand2:first').click();
});
```